# IIS Rewrite Rule - negate when query string contains a word

Tags: redirect, https, url-rewriting, config, url-rewrite-module

I have a rewrite rule to force HTTPS on my site but I need to negate it for a pages that contain a particular query string.

This is the rule in my web config. I'm going this url:

```
mysite.com/data/map?loc=45&loct=2&clean=true&isForImage=true#2/any/false/869/68/13517/Orange/
```

but I still get redirected to https. Why isn't my pattern working?

Answer (score 1):

You rule is correct:

```
<rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
   <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="isForImage=true" negate="true"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

Most probably your browser cached 301 redirect (most browsers do that). Can you please clear your browser's cache and try to visit `mysite.com/data/map?loc=45&loct=2&clean=true&isForImage=true#2/any/false/869/68/13517/Orange/` again